# Group by and sum in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Say I have a dataframe like such:

```
df= { 'class': ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
         'ID':[1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5]}  

Class ID
A     1 
A     2 
A     2 
A     3 
A     3 
B     4 
B     4 
B     4 
B     5
```

I'd like to summarize the data as such:

```
Class  count(distinct(ID))
A      3
B      2
```

I know this is pretty trivial but I've gotten stuck here:

`df.groupby(by=['Class', 'ID']).count()`

which gives me

[image]

I can't seem to get the summation after the group by for some reason.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
In [11]: df.groupby("Class")["ID"].nunique()
Out[11]:
Class
A    3
B    2
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(df[['Class','ID']]
 .drop_duplicates()
 .groupby('Class')
 .count())
```